# RandomUtils.nextLong(10L,1000L) fails with "unexpected token: 10L" in JMeter HTTP Request body

Tags: performance, groovy, jmeter, apache-commons

I have to pass a random long value in one of my HTTP request body data.

The code I used is `"${__groovy(import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;RandomUtils.nextLong(10L,1000L);)}"`

I have tried the relevant groovy code in JSR223 preprocessor for groovy and it prints out the number correctly;

```
long rand = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(2000, 10000);
log.info("random   [" + rand + "]");
```

But when I user the same code in __groovy() inside the HTTP Request body, it fails with ;

```
2020-03-06 09:50:57,821 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: random   [4023]
2020-03-06 09:50:57,827 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script358.groovy: 1: unexpected token: 10L @ line 1, column 66.
   domUtils;RandomUtils.nextLong(10L
                                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:162) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy.execute(Groovy.java:121) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:136) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:111) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:101) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument.getValue(Argument.java:146) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument.getEncodedValue(HTTPArgument.java:248) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument.getEncodedValue(HTTPArgument.java:229) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.setupHttpEntityEnclosingRequestData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1529) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.handleMethod(HTTPHC4Impl.java:794) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:569) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
```

I can see I can get other groovy scripts like ***"${__groovy(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");)}"*** working fine inside the HTTP Request Body Data.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE :** I also tried the code without "L" even `RandomUtils.nextLong(10,1000);` same exception.

Comment: Tried that also ...  `2020-03-06 11:03:29,855 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: random   [3387]
2020-03-06 11:03:29,861 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script362.groovy: 1: unexpected token: 10 @ line 1, column 66.
   domUtils;RandomUtils.nextLong(10
                                 ^
` .  Same result

Comment: The groovy code I used in the HTTP REquest Body `"${__groovy(import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;RandomUtils.nextLong(10,1000);)}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy

> Argument values that themselves contain commas should be escaped as necessary. If you need to include a comma in your parameter value, escape it like this: `\,`

so, it should be like this:

`${__groovy( org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(10\,1000) )}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the comma like:

```
${__groovy(return org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(10\, 1000),)}
```

Next time consider using [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) in order to get the correct syntax for JMeter Functions.

In general it's recommended to use JMeter's built-in test elements and/or functions and avoid scripting where possible so consider using [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) instead, the relevant syntax would be:

```
${__Random(10,1000,)}
```

if you provide the 3rd parameter - JMeter will store the generated value in the variable.

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/)